# different output from same function with same parameters

Tags: php, string, string-length

I am confused with following string function

`echo strlen("l\n2"); //give 3 in output`

where as

`echo strlen('l\n2'); //give 4 in output`

can anybody explain why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you use single quotes (' '), PHP does not expand the `\n` as a single new line character whereas in double quotes (" "), `\n` translates to the new line character (ie. a single character) thus giving 3 characters

Taken from PHP's String Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: yeah right, i was confused with it, in fact i usually get confused with string quotes, Thanks for quick response

Answer (score 4):

`\n` is not parsed as a newline character when the string is wrapped in single quotes. Instead, it is treated as a literal `\` followed by `n`.